# Tkinter not found in pycharm

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, pycharm

I want to use the tkinter module and PyCharm is making it difficult. I am using the Python 3.7 Interpreter, and I have not been able to use it.

I have tried a few things:

```
pip install tkinter
pip3 install tkinter
sudo apt install tkinter
sudo apt install python-tk
```

None of these have success

Whenever I use `import tkinter`, it just returns the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/removed/PycharmProjects/Tutorials/GUI.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tkinter
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Anyone know of a solution?

Comment: Figured it out. Just had to reinstall and use a different interpreter! Funny how it only worked after I posted this question only

Comment: Yeah, you can configure which interpreter to use for each project.  Yours probably didn't have the expected interpreter selected.

Comment: If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved to your satisfaction, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for a full explanation.

Comment: Sorry for belated repsonse. That was the first thing I tried, turns out it was just the snap package for Pycharm that was being dumb. Thanks anyways. I'll accept it anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always make sure you have the right interpreter selected;

In PyCharm, you can check this by pressing ctrl + alt + s, and navigating to the "project interpreter" tab. Here you can select the different python installations on your system.

[image]

Comment: How do I know which one is the right interpreter? I need to install a different version of Python? This is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 0):

This thread might be a little old but I had the same problem for the past 3 days. My solution was as follows (btw I'm running Linux Mint 19 Cinnamon with python3.x):
-Remove PyCharm (I had installed it via Linux Mint's software center)
-Download PyCharm from the JetBrains website.

the "tkinter" module was by installed and recognized by default.